# Продвинутая система оценки (как в github)

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, алгоритм

к примеру, в `Github` (да и в facebook), есть интересная система оценки комментария

[image: reload]

Пытаюсь понять как все это происходит, понял пока что:

Есть отдельная таблица с полями: `id_user`, `comment_id`, `flag`

Где `flag`, заранее продуманная таблица (в уме), то есть если `flag = 1`, то поставили `+1`, `flag = 2` — `-1`. Обычная связывающая таблица

Как же грамотно организовать запрос к БД, чтобы все нормально получить? Или нужно велосипедами все после получения результата обрабатывать?